# Can you grow or change a feature on the same turn it’s added?

Tags: actions, targeting, cozy-town

In the game [Cozy Town](https://temporalhiccup.itch.io/cozy-town), you pull a card on every turn from the appropriate deck and check it against the town oracle. The oracle then gives a choice of events for what happens in the town this week. After the event is discussed and the question answered, the active player has a choice of three actions to take that each change the town in some way, including growing or changing a feature of the town.

Some of the events require adding new features to the map in some way, such as new stores or houses for newcomers. **Can the active player change or grow a feature that has been added on that same turn?**

For example, if it’s spring and I pull the 10 of hearts, I can choose the event “A new lovely forest suddenly appears nearby.” I then say I want some of the townsfolk to make a fence around it so that it can be protected from the hungry bunnies who roam the town (this is an actual example from my game). Is that my action for the turn, since I changed the forest in some way? Or do I need to pick a different action/target instead, since it was just added?

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to this game, it looks fantastic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### As long as you've made it a feature of the town, sure.

When you're adding new elements to the map as the result of a card draw, you can put them in the same special categories that you used for the elements you selected at the start of the game - a town **feature**, a **friend** of the town, or even an upcoming **event** - as long as the players at your table agree that they belong in that category.

(A new forest might just be nearby and not part of the town proper, but the people who live there can be **friends** of the town. Or it might be the migratory forest that shows up here every year for an **event**, our town flower festival -- OH GEEZ WE FORGOT ABOUT THE FLOWER FESTIVAL)

As a result, as long as you've added it in that category, you're free to interact appropriately with it with your followup action - it's just like it was a feature of the town from the very beginning.

This is the same way that the original Quiet Year worked - any of the game elements could interact with the special categories of things on the map, like abundances and scarcities. It's just that the Quiet Year took place in a much less cozy world, and as a result the table was encouraged to only use long-running projects to address scarcities and create abundances.